# Error enviar correo via PHPMailer SMTP

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Intento enviar un correo por PHPMailer pero cuando le doy a Submit me salta una pagina que pone "Esta página no funciona". Mi proposito es tener la pagina en un dominio y tener un apartado contactos, pero no consigo solucionar este problema.

PHP:

```
<?php 

require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'Exception.php';
require 'OAuth.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

            $mail->isSMTP();                                      
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
            $mail->Username = "ejemplo@gmail.com";                 
            $mail->Password = "ejemplo";                           
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
            $mail->Port = 465;                                   

            $mail->setFrom("destino@gmail.com", 'Dsmart Tutorials');
            $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);     

            $mail->addReplyTo("ejemplo@gmail.com");
            $mail->isHTML(false);                                  

            $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
            $mail->Body    = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: ". $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];

            if(!$mail->send()) {
                echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo 'Message has been sent';
            }
  
?>
```

HTML:

```
    <form method="POST" action="php/email.php" class="container contact" name="send_email">
        <div class="contact-inputs title">
            <h1>Explicanos <span class="change-how">tu proyecto</span></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-inputs name">
            <input type="text" name="name" id="" placeholder="Nombre y apellidos" class="form-input input-name">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-inputs email">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="" placeholder="Email" class="form-input input-email">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-inputs phone">
            <input type="number" name="phone" id="" placeholder="Teléfono" class="form-input input-phone">
        </div>
        <div class="contact-inputs message">
            <textarea type="radio" name="message" id="" placeholder="Mensaje" class="form-input input-message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-inputs submit">
            <input name="submit" type="submit" value="ENVIAR" class="btn-general btn-submit">
        </div>
    </form>
```

He revisado varias veces el codigo y no entiendo porque no entra al archivo email.php dado que todos los parametros estan bien configurados. (Utilizo un servidor XAMPP para hacer las pruebas)

Comment: ¿Aquí `$mail->setFrom(EMAIL, 'Dsmart Tutorials');` `EMAIL` es una constante? ¿Dónde la defines?

Comment: @A.Cedano Las variable CORREO, PASSWORD y EMAIL son variables de ejemplo, en el php esta bien puesto, en el caso de EMAIL pongo el correo que ponen en el html (remitente)

Comment: @A.Cedano lo he modificado para que quede mas claro

Comment: intentante dejar en blanco el email.php poniendo un simple echo "hola" si ahi entra bien es porque hay un problem con el require de la libreria.

Comment: Cuando falla PHP es una buena costumbre mirar el fichero error.log generado en el lado del servidor para ver el error. Puede que email.php no esté en la carpeta php o que los require no estén en la misma carpeta que email.php o que haya un error de sintaxis o de lógica, nada que error.log no pueda mostrar.

Comment: A partir de un echo he descubierto que salta el error cuando llega a $mail = new PHPMailer;

Answer (score 0):

Intenta el siguiente código para casar el posible error si es que se da al ejecutar el php de la pagina:

```
<?php

try {

    if (!file_exists('PHPMailer.php')) {
        throw new Exception('PHPMailer.php no existe');
    }
    if (!file_exists('SMTP.php')) {
        throw new Exception('SMTP.php does no existe');
    }
    if (!file_exists('Exception.php')) {
        throw new Exception('Exception.php no existe');
    }

    if (!file_exists('OAuth.php')) {
        throw new Exception('OAuth.php no existe');
    }
    use "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer"
    //use "PHPMailer\PHPMailer";
    require 'PHPMailer.php';
    require 'SMTP.php';
    require 'Exception.php';
    require 'OAuth.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "ejemplo@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "ejemplo";
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
    $mail->Port = 465;

    $mail->setFrom("destino@gmail.com", 'Dsmart Tutorials');
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);

    $mail->addReplyTo("ejemplo@gmail.com");
    $mail->isHTML(false);
    $mail->WordWrap = 50;
    $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mail->Body = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    $mail->AltBody = "Telefono: " . $_POST['phone'] . "\n\n" . "Correo: " . $_POST['email'] . "\n\n" . $_POST['message'];
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message has been sent';
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Excepción capturada: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: Probando con un "echo" he descubierto que el problema lo tengo cuando llega a $mail = new PHPMailer;

Comment: Hola Victor, creo que es la ruta de la clase ve el ejemplo modificado con use PHPMailer\PHPMailer o use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer